# composition of functions is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Question is as follows : Let $X,Y,Z$ are metric Spaces

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous map onto $Y$ and let $X$ be compact. Also $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ such that $g\circ f:X\rightarrow Z$ is continuous. Show that $g$ is continuous.

I do not even know how to start this question..

Please give some **hints**.. *[**Not** looking for nor wanting a full answer]*

Do i have to check that inverse image of open set is open under $g$ or is there any other methods?

$U$ is open in $Z$ so, $(g\circ f)^{-1}(U)$ is open.. i.e., $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(U))$ is open... I do not think this is a better way to proceed...

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but "onto $Y$" is an essential part, for if $f$ is not required to be surjective, $g$ can be discontinuous on the part of $Y$ missed by $f$. An example using the reals: $f(x) = x^2$; $g(x) = 1$ for $x \ge 0$, $g(x) = -1$ for $x < 0$.

Comment: Yes Yes.. I got it... Thanks @JohnHughes

Comment: Is $Y$ assumed to be Hausdorff?

Comment: No.. It is not assumed to be Hausdorff.. @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for DanielFischer's comment. The following assumes $Y$ is Hausdorff in order to make point 5 to be true.

Hints:

1. Start with closed set $C$ in $Z$. There is an equivalent definition for continuity of $g$ with respect to closed sets.
2. By surjective of $f$, we know $f(f^{-1}(A))=A$ for any set $A$ in $Y$.
3. Use continuity of $g\circ f$ and $f$.
4. Note closed subsets in a compact space is compact.
5. Note image of any compact set under continuous function is compact , which is also closed .

Comment: I have requested for a hint...

Comment: Please delete this answer and see if you can help me with hints.. I am not even reading this answer...

Comment: @cello I have modified the answer to hints. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... It helped..

Comment: @cello I am glad to hear that.

Comment: I can not upvote as i do not have enough reputation... I wil upvote once i get some reputation... Thanks again..

Comment: Not in all spaces are (quasi)compact subsets closed. (Spaces in which that is the case are called KC spaces.) Probably, this is the intended argument, but for it to work, an additional condition on $Y$ is needed. (cc @cello)

Comment: @DanielFischer : Ok... So, how do we proceed then..

Comment: @cello Good question. Point is, without further assumptions on $Y$, $g$ need not be continuous. Let $X = Z = [0,1]$ with the standard topology, and $Y = [0,1]$ with the indiscrete topology, and $f = g = \operatorname{id}$. Then $f$ is a continuous surjection, $g\circ f$ is continuous, but $g$ isn't continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not know what i am supposed to do now... It was given to be show that ****....

Comment: @cello Either you're in a context where the argument works (e.g. if you only consider metric spaces), or you have a counterexample. It wouldn't be the first time in history that an exercise contains an error.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Ok.. Os, if we consider metric spaces then it does work.. May be it is a typo...